# How to extract a variety of zip files without knowing the extension in bash

Tags: bash, zip, tar

I'm writing a bash script which needs to handle a bunch of zip files with different possibilities (primarily tar.gz, zip, and rar). Is there a tool I can get that does this, so I could call "toolname filename", and if not, how do I determine the extension of a file (so that I can make a case statement with the different required tools)?

Comment: You could find the file's magic number to verify the file extension or using the "file" command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can make a complex shell script to handle this.  But, you don't need to.  [The right tool is `7z`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7z_%28file_format%29).  It will natively handle all the compression formats that you mention and many many more.

For example, `allfiles-` is a zip archive (note that the extension is missing).  To list its contents, use the `l` (ell) function:

```
$ 7z l allfiles-

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,2 CPUs)

Listing archive: allfiles-

--
Path = allfiles-
Type = zip
Physical Size = 367

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2015-03-10 21:05:40 .....           29           29  file1
2015-03-10 21:05:42 .....           29           29  file2
2015-03-10 21:05:44 .....           29           29  file3
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
                                    87           87  3 files, 0 folders
```

Note that `7z` does not depend on having the right extension.  It figured out the type of archive itself.

The functions supported by `7z` are:

```
   a      Add
   d      Delete
   e      Extract
   l      List
   t      Test
   u      Update/Create
   x      eXtract with full paths
```

Among the file formats supported by `7z` are: LZMA2,  XZ,  ZIP,  Zip64,
CAB,  RAR, ARJ, GZIP, BZIP2, TAR, CPIO, RPM, ISO, as well as most filesystem images and DEB formats.

To install `7z` on a Debian-like system, run:

```
apt-get install p7zip-full
```

Comment: Thank you! I really was hoping for a tool rather than a complex bash solution as that would be much more simple, but I didn't know 7z could handle all of them.

Comment: For completeness, I'd like to note that 7z needs to be run twice on .tar.gz files

Answer (score 2):

One possibly more reliable way of recognizing a file's type is the `file` tool, which uses a database of identifying patterns to recognize a file's format. Some useful options:

- `file --mime-type` prints only a mimetype (such as `application/zip` or `application/x-gzip`) which is easy to parse (or match)
- `file -i` prints the mimetype and other parameters such as `charset` (not relevant for compressed files)
- `file -z` also attempts to decompress the file (doesn't work with all archive formats), which is the best way to distinguish simple gzipped files from gzipped tar archives.

You almost certainly have it installed, but if not: [the file homepage](http://www.darwinsys.com/file/)

Answer (score 1):

The bash pattern matching operator `##` is often used to extract part of a filename this way.  If `$filename` contains the name of a file, then the expression `${filename##*.}` is the filename after removing the longest string matching the pattern `*.`, i.e. the filename extension.

```
$ filename=foo.tgz
$ echo ${filename##*.}
tgz
```

That might not be the best option for your situation, if some of the files really might have a compound extension like `tar.gz`.  When the pattern you're looking for is more variable, you will probably want to use something like a nested globbing statement:

```
if [[ $filename = *.tar.gz ]]; then
    tar xzf $filename
elif [[ $filename = *.zip ]]; then
    unzip $filename
elif [[ $filename = *rar ]]; then
    unrar $filename
fi
```